# Error when I call a text file with pascal

Tags: file, pascal

I'm trying to call an existing file but the code returns **EInOutError//File not found**
at line reset(f)

I am sure the address name is correct and the file exists

```
Begin
assign(f,'C:\Desktop\Source.txt');

reset(f);

assign(f1,'Crypt.txt');
ReWrite(f1);
saisir(cle);
 affiche(f);
close(f);
close(f1);
end.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you sure the path is ```C:\Desktop\Source.txt```?  It either has no access to that file (i.e. file permissions aren't right)  or you specified the wrong path.

Comment: Are you certain that you don't need to escape (or double) the backslash in the path?

Comment: You should always assign the filename to a String variable and use that to assign the file after testing that it exists.  E.g. `var AFileName : String; ... AFileName := 'C:\Desktop\Source.txt'; Assert(FileExists(AFileName));  Assign(F, AFileName)`  Btw, the default desktop folder under Windows is **not** directly under the root of C:.  Also, on Windows at least, the backslash does **not** need to be escaped.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: No, Pascal does not require backslashes in paths to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

you should try these:
-Use another pascal compiler like Free pascal, etc 
-Assign the file name to a string 
-Turn ON 'Show hidden files, folders and drivers' and turn OFF 'Hide extensions for known type file'.I used to have this problem, I tried this and somehow it's worked for me 
Good luck!

Comment: There is no "somehow" in Pascal programming, particularly not Free Pascal.  Btw, your last two points will have no effect whatever to the operation of the code in the q.